# Unable to call component method. Public method [__v_raw] not found on component: []

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, sortable

buenos día tardes o noches .

Estoy usando la librería https://github.com/asantibanez/laravel-blade-sortable/blob/master/README.md , pero al momento de  usar
mi componente:

```
    public function handleSortOrderChange($sortOrder, $previousSortOrder, $name, $from, $to){

     \Log::info("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
     \Log::info($sortOrder);
     \Log::info($previousSortOrder);
     \Log::info($name);
    \Log::info($from);
    \Log::info($to);
    \Log::info("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
```

```
<x-laravel-blade-sortable::sortable
    name="dropzone"
    wire:onSortOrderChange="handleSortOrderChange"
>
    {{-- Items here --}}
</x-laravel-blade-sortable::sortable>
```

me bota el error de  `Unable to call component method. Public method [__v_raw] not found on component: [nombre_de_componente]` según el cual mi método no esta definido publico , pero si esta . como ven estoy mandando a imprimir en el log , pero no imprime nada . Help me please π π π π π π π π π!!!

Comment: Hola Mauricio como estás, quisiera preguntarte si pudiste solucionar el problema, es que me pasa exactamente lo mismo, te agradezco de antemano si compartes la solución.

Comment: No, cambie a Sortablejs .https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable , no pude solucionarlo @LeonardoValencia